# C++ - Definition of 2d matrices of type std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, stdarray

I am looking to define two 2d matrices: `f` and `f_transpose` of the type: `std::array <std::array <float, 3>, dim>` and  `std::array <std::array <float, dim>, 3>`. The value of `dim` is `23`.

I want elements `f[0][0]`, `f[1][1]`, `f[2][2]`, `f_transpose[0][0]`, `f_transpose[1][1]` and `f_transpose[2][2]` to be `1` and the rest of the elements `0`.

These arrays are global variables and I tried the following:

```
static array <array <float, 3>, dim> f = {{{{1}}, {{0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 1}}}};
static array <array <float, dim>, 3> f_transpose = {{{{1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 1}}}};
```

This does give me `1` in necessary places, but some of the values that should be `0` are `1` or `-1`. My understanding is that whatever is not defined will be considered `0`, but clearly that's not what is happening. How do I get around this problem?

**Edit:**

I had to remove the `github` link present here earlier. But for the answer (and comment) to make sense, I have added the relevant function below:

```
void print_ffamily(){

    cout << "F Matrix" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++){
                printf("%0.2f ", f[i][j]);

            }
            cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "F transposed Matrix" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                printf("%0.2f ", f_transpose[i][j]);

            }
            cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m pretty sure both are correct.

For both you started [*list-initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) which is an [*aggregate initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) in this case.

For `f_transpose` you started an initializer for each of the 3 sub-arrays, the missing elements of each array are [*value-initialized*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) which means *zero-initialized* for `float`.
For `f` you specify initializers for 3 arrays, for their elements the above applies too. The remaining arrays are indirectly (via *value-initializaion*,
 < C++11) or directly (≥ C++11) *aggregate-initialized* which *value-initializes* and therefore *zero-initializes* all their elements because the initializer is empty.

Are you verifying the contents correctly?

Comment: Yes. I believe so. However, I am planning to double check everything A - Z to see if any other part of the code is creating problems. But this is the latest snippet I added and everything so far worked fine. I shall update after checking everything.

Comment: In `print_ffamily` you iterate `f` as if it was `f_transpose` and the other way around for `f_transpose`. Just to clarify: C++ is row-major, `f` has 23 rows with 3 elements each and `f_transpose` vice versa.

Comment: That was a very silly mistake. Thank You for pointing it out.

Comment: consider using loops like: `for (auto && row : mat) {
            for (auto && elem : row) {
                std::cout << elem << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << '\n'
        }` to prevent such issues. `std::array` knows its own size, leverage that.